# Music producing software for PC has the smart instruments of Garageband

Tags: music-production

I once owned an iPad and have used Garageband a lot. Now, I am looking for a similar software that I can produce amateur music easily.

Although I have searched this on the internet ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/WeAreTheMusicMakers/comments/16b6n3/is_there_an_equivalent_to_smart_instruments_in/), [2](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-garageband-alternatives-music-production-windows/)), and even [asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200247/keys-of-a-particular-scale-only-in-garageband-on-os-x) a question in apple.SE, I could not get a proper answer.

What I look for is a music producing software for Windows or Linux, that enables *key scaling*, in which an instrument is changed to a virtual instrument, which only contains the keys of that particular scale.

I have not come across such software. Would you share it with me if you happen to know one?

It does not matter if it is free or not.

P.S. Only Garageband in iPad has this feature, it is not present in Macbooks or iMacs!

Comment: What OS? Gratis or Commercial?

Comment: @Tom I have added the details. By the way, are you the Tom from tomshardware?

Comment: No, sadly I'm not that famous yet:) I usually go by the username of "onlineth" but I figured for SE I would use my first name as I haven't seen that many other "tom"s out there